# Macro to edit strings and write them on other sheet

Tags: excel, database, string, vba, edit

I'm a noob at programing and i'm having a hard time trying to figure out how could i accomplish my task.

I Have a template sheet that is organized in a way that after it has been filled, it will be converted to ".csv" and then imported to a program do build a database.

And i have another Sheet with some the data i need and some that i dont need. 
The first column i want to read is the "Tag Names" that follows this model above:

TAG NAMES        /// LOW   /// HIGH /// ELU

80-PIT-0001    ///   0    ///  1   ///  C

32-XI-004B     ///   1    ///  0   ///  C

45-CIT-4001    ///   0    ///  1   ///  D

I need to get all these tags and:

a) remove the "-" from tag names
b) write the tag names without "-" in the template sheet
c) when writing it to the template sheet it has to add "_PV" and "_PB" at the end of the tag name. Each one need to be in a difrent line.
d) All attributes need to be copied aswell

Just like this:

80PIT0001_PV    ///   0    ///  1   ///  C

80PIT0001_PB    ///   0    ///  1   ///  C

32XI004B_PV    ///   1    ///  0   ///  C

32XI004B_PB    ///   1    ///  0   ///  C

45CIT4001_PV   ///   0    ///  1   ///  D

45CIT4001_PB   ///   0    ///  1   ///  D

If somebody could give me a light on how to manipulate and edit properly these strings and how to write these to a new sheet, in my case, the template sheet.

I Really Thanks anyone that would try to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, written on mobile, but maybe something like this. I assume that your data (excluding column headers/names) begins in cell A2 on a sheet called 'Source' -- and that the data is column A is contiguous.

Save a copy of your workbook before running code, as code will try to overwrite data on sheet 'Template' (assuming it exists).

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillTemplateSheet()

With Thisworkbook

' Change this to whatever sheet your data is on and change cell reference to the first tag name (excluding header) '
With .worksheets("Source").range("A2")

Dim lastRow as long
lastRow = .end(xldown).row ' This is not the best way to find the last row, but might work in your use case '

Dim arrayOfValues() as variant
arrayOfValues = .resize(lastRow - .row+1, 4).value2 ' Assumes we want the first four columns '

End with

Dim rowIndex as long
Dim columnIndex as long
Dim alteredTagName as string

' Appending PV and PB to each tag name means we basically need twice as many body rows in the output.'

Dim outputArray() as variant
Redim outputArray(lbound(arrayOfValues,1) to (ubound(arrayOfValues,1)*2), lbound(arrayOfValues,2) to ubound(arrayOfValues,2))

For rowIndex = lbound(arrayOfValues,1) to ubound(arrayOfValues,1)

For columnIndex = lbound(arrayOfValues,2) to ubound(arrayOfValues,2)

If columnIndex <> 1 then
' d) copy all other attributes to outputArray'

outputArray(rowIndex, columnIndex) = arrayOfValues(rowIndex,columnIndex)

outputArray(rowIndex+1, columnIndex) = arrayOfValues(rowIndex,columnIndex)

Else

alteredTagName = arrayOfValues(rowIndex,columnIndex) 

'a) get rid of all - '
alteredTagName = vba.strings.join(VBA.strings.split(alteredTagName,"-",-1,vbbinarycompare),vbnullstring)

'b) write to output array '
'c) append PV and PB '

outputArray(rowIndex, columnIndex) = alteredTagname & "_PV"

outputArray (rowIndex +1, columnIndex) = alteredTagName & "_PB"

End if

Next columnIndex

Next rowIndex

End with

' Assumes headers are on row 1 of sheet Template, and therefore first tag name will be in cell A2'
.worksheets("Template").range("A2").resize(ubound(outputArray,1),ubound(outputArray,2)).value2 = outputArray

End with

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you don't exactly need programming to achieve this. This is achievable using formulas in both Excel and Google Sheets. **Substitute** formula will remove the '-' and concatenate formula in combination with **IF** and **ROW** will add the '_PV'. **Arrayformula** on top of these other formulas will do this calculation in the entire column without having to drag-down the formula each time.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that "The Boss" wants me to develop a macro to achieve it. He wants a shiny button that can do it automatically. I just need to understand how i can work with strings in that way.

Thanks again for your help my friend.